# Unassisted triple play in baseball - how was it done?

Tags: lateral-thinking, sports

In a baseball game the bases are loaded and there are no outs.  One player put out three of the opposing players in one play without involving any of his team mates.  How did he do it?

Comment: How is this lateral thinking, or a puzzle for that matter? Unassisted triple plays aren't unheard of in baseball - seems more like sports trivia.

Comment: You must have read my Facebook post.

Comment: Of course he did! Next time you post a riddle, make sure not to post the solution on facebook moments before.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it appears to be a sports trivia question, not a puzzle.

Answer (score 3):

> The shortstop caught a line drive, stepped on second base before the runner tagged up, and tagged the runner from first who had started running during the pitch. This  has happened [eight times](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unassisted_triple_play) in MLB history, and seven more times substituting the first or second baseman for the shortstop.